# No Such Element - No Line Found (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm creating a program which prints a summary of the situation after interactive input has ended (ctrl - d). So it prints a summary of the average age and percentage of children who have received vaccines after interactive input.

However, I'm always receiving the No Line Found error whenever I press ctrl-d at Name:. My compiler tells me the error is at name = sc.nextLine(); within the while loop but I don't know what is causing the error exactly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = new String();
        int age, num = 0, i, totalAge = 0;
        boolean vaccinated;
        int numVaccinated = 0;
        double average = 0, percent = 0, count = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
            System.out.print("Age: ");
            age = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Age is " + age);
            System.out.print("Vaccinated for chickenpox? ");
            vaccinated = sc.nextBoolean();

            totalAge += age;
            num++;

            if(vaccinated == true)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Vaccinated for chickenpox");
            }
            else
            {   
                System.out.println("Not vaccinated for chickenpox");
            }

        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {   
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Name is \"" + name + "\"");
            System.out.print("Age: ");
            age = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Age is " + age);
            System.out.print("Vaccinated for chickenpox? ");
            vaccinated = sc.nextBoolean();

            totalAge += age;
            num++;

            if(vaccinated == true)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Vaccinated for chickenpox");
            }
            else
            {   
                System.out.println("Not vaccinated for chickenpox");
            }
        }

        average = (double) totalAge/num;

        percent = (double) count/num * 100;

        System.out.printf("Average age is %.2f\n", average);
        System.out.printf("Percentage of children vaccinated is %.2f%%\n", percent);

    }
}
```

Comment: I executed your code and I do not get any errors. However, the loop goes on and on forever without having any chance to cancel. At least if I use the command line eclipse provides, I suppose you use the terminal?

Comment: I use ctrl-d to end input after entering 1 set of data. But I receive  Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Answer (score 0):

You do not correctly implement an exit condition for your loop if you ask me.

Try something like this:

```
String input = "";
do {
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name = sc.nextLine();
    [... all your input parameters ...]
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Do you want to enter another child (y/n)? ");
    input = sc.nextLine();
} while (!input.equals("n"));
```

This way you can quit entering new persons without having to enter a strange command that might lead to an error. Furthermore, a `do-while` loop helps you to reduce your code, because you don't have to use the same code twice, i.e., everything between `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` and `while(sc.hasNextLine())` in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the app I'm trying to make ends when it reaches end of input (ctrl-d). Is there a way to resolve the conflict between ending input and sc.nextLine();?